# How to configure MAAS to be able to boot virtual machines

Tags: juju, kvm-virtualization, maas, virtualization

I am running a virtual (kvm) MAAS/juju setup where most of the MAAS nodes (including MAAS master) are virtual, but some are also physical nodes. The physical Dell 1950 nodes configures automatically for boot in MAAS, so when i deploy via Juju they power on automatically. My problem lies in trying to set up boot for virtual systems. I see the posibility in the MAAS for power type. I can choose virsh. But i need to fill in information i do not know. What should i fill in for Driver and Power ID?

Anyone has experience with that?

Comment: i am trying to get that kvm and maas ,
please explain how you setup all the things to get working

Answer (score 22):

In maas 1.2 through 1.8 the virsh power type requires only the Address and Power ID.

MAAS 1.8 Screenshot
[image: MAAS 1.8 virsh power settings]

MAAS 1.2-1.4 Screenshot
[image: MAAS 1.2-1.4 virsh power settings]

The `libvirt-bin` package needs to be installed to get the `virsh` command

```
$ sudo apt-get -y install libvirt-bin
```

the `Power ID` is the name of the virtual machine shown by `sudo virsh list --all`

The address is a normal libvirt connect string:

```
qemu+ssh://ubuntu@10.0.0.2/system
```

or

```
qemu:///system
```

If you want to use ssh you'll need to generate a ssh key pair for the maas user. By default there is no home directory created for the maas user.

```
$ sudo mkdir -p ~maas
$ sudo chown maas:maas ~maas
```

Add a login shell for the maas user (we'll only need this for the `ssh-copy-id` command later; if you're putting ssh keys in place manually or using a different mechanism, this step isn't strictly needed):

```
$ sudo chsh -s /bin/bash maas
```

Generate a SSH keypair as the maas user (hit enter three times to accept the default path and empty password):

```
$ sudo -u maas ssh-keygen
Generating public/private rsa key pair.
Enter file in which to save the key (/home/maas/.ssh/id_rsa): 
Created directory '/home/maas/.ssh'.
Enter passphrase (empty for no passphrase): 
Enter same passphrase again: 
Your identification has been saved in /home/maas/.ssh/id_rsa.
Your public key has been saved in /home/maas/.ssh/id_rsa.pub.
```

Then add the public key to `~ubuntu/.ssh/authorized_keys` on the vm server so virsh can use ssh without a password:

```
$ sudo -u maas -i ssh-copy-id ubuntu@10.0.0.2
```

As the maas user, test virsh commands against libvirt at 10.0.0.2:

```
$ sudo -u maas virsh -c qemu+ssh://ubuntu@10.0.0.2/system list --all
```

Comment: I'm putting this answer in the official MAAS docs. Thanks!

Comment: But what do you do if `virsh -c qemu:///system list --all` is an empty result set?

Comment: Running `virsh -c qemu:///system list --all` on the 10.0.0.2 machine is equivalent to running `virsh -c qemu+ssh://ubuntu@10.0.0.2/system list --all` on another machine, provided the "ubuntu" user on 10.0.0.2 is added to the "libvirtd" group (i.e. can access running KVM nodes) and has an authorized SSH key to allow you to connect to ubuntu@10.0.0.2 without a password.

Comment: Your KVM virtual machines might be owned by the root account, not a normal user. Then you need to connect using `qemu+ssh://root@10.0.0.2/system` instead, and the SSH key needs to allow passwordless access to `root`, not the `ubuntu` user. Needless to say, this is **rather insecure** :)

Answer (score 1):

Driver and Username are not required for virsh. They will be deleted eventually.b