# MAAS, JUJU, VirtualBox 4.3 and virsh command

Tags: virtualbox, virtualization

I've a problem with `libvirt 1.2.2` and VirtualBox 4.3.

After installing Ubuntu 14.04 server and setting `MAAS` and `JUJU`, I need to use `virsh` to see the list of my installed VM (as reported in the guide [How to configure MAAS to be able to boot virtual machines](https://askubuntu.com/questions/292061/how-to-configure-maas-to-be-able-to-boot-virtual-machines).)
I've also created 2 other nodes and set `MAAS` server correctly, but when trying to use `virsh` to see the list of the installed VM I don't receive any list.

The command is that:

```
sudo virsh list --all
```

While, if I run this

```
sudo virsh -c vbox:///session
```

the answer is that

> libvir: error : could not connect to vbox:///session
>   error: failed to connect to the hypervisor

Is there someone, who have had the same issue and how to resolve it?