# openstack-install: unit postgresql hook failed db-admin-relation-changed

Tags: maas, openstack

Background: I'm following http://www.ubuntu.com/download/cloud/install-ubuntu-openstack. I've got one PM (16 cores, 48GB RAM), running 7 (initially empty) VMs, which were created using virt-install. I used virt-install to create two NAT'ed networks: 'private' to which all 7 VMs are attached and 'public' to which only 2 are attached. The PM runs MAAS and provides DHCP & DNS only on the 'private' network. (I chose the names 'private' and 'public' as I assumed that one of the required networks would be for doing MAAS/openstack-y stuff, and the other would be for accessing whatever service ultimately gets deployed on the (nested) VMs that will ultimately get created). The systems get enlisted and commissioned so that, by the end of step 3 in the Ubuntu procedure, I have 7 nodes, all marked 'Ready'.

Problem: As per step 4 in the Ubuntu procedure, I run `openstack-install`, provide the MAAS key, specify the MAAS server as the PM's IP on the 'private' network, and after about 15 minutes it fails.

Other info: The status line of openstack-install's TUI says 'Downloading latest Landscape Autopilot bundle...'; the bottom of ~root/.cloud-install/commands.log says:

```
[ERROR • 06-30 13:23:40] • cloudinstall.multi_install • (multi_install.py, run_deployer, 770)]
   Problem deploying Landscape: {'status': 1, 'output': '2015-06-30 13:09:11 [DEBUG] deployer.cli: Using runtime GoEnvironment on maas\n2015-06-30 13:09:11 [INFO] deployer.cli: Starting deployment of landscape-dense-maas\n2015-06-30 13:09:11 [DEBUG] deployer.import: Getting charms...\n2015-06-30 13:09:11 [DEBUG] deployer.charm: Cache dir /root/.cloud-install/juju/.deployer-store-cache/cs_trusty_haproxy-4\n2015-06-30 13:09:11 [DEBUG] deployer.charm: Retrieving store charm cs:trusty/haproxy-4\n2015-06-30 13:09:11 [DEBUG] deployer.charm: Cache dir /root/.cloud-install/juju/.deployer-store-cache/cs_trusty_rabbitmq-server-26\n2015-06-30 13:09:11 [DEBUG] deployer.charm: Retrieving store charm cs:trusty/rabbitmq-server-26\n2015-06-30 13:09:11 [DEBUG] deployer.charm: Cache dir /root/.cloud-install/juju/.deployer-store-cache/cs_trusty_postgresql-15\n2015-06-30 13:09:11 [DEBUG] deployer.charm: Retrieving store charm cs:trusty/postgresql-15\n2015-06-30 13:09:12 [DEBUG] deployer.charm: Cache dir /root/.cloud-install/juju/.deployer-store-cache/cs_trusty_landscape-server\n2015-06-30 13:09:12 [DEBUG] deployer.charm: Retrieving store charm cs:trusty/landscape-server-10\n2015-06-30 13:09:12 [DEBUG] deployer.charm: Cache dir /root/.cloud-install/juju/.deployer-store-cache/cs_trusty_landscape-server\n2015-06-30 13:09:12 [DEBUG] deployer.charm: Cache dir /root/.cloud-install/juju/.deployer-store-cache/cs_trusty_apache2-10\n2015-06-30 13:09:12 [DEBUG] deployer.charm: Retrieving store charm cs:trusty/apache2-10\n2015-06-30 13:09:12 [DEBUG] deployer.deploy: Resolving configuration\n2015-06-30 13:09:12 [DEBUG] deployer.env: Connecting to environment...\n2015-06-30 13:09:13 [DEBUG] deployer.env: Connected to environment\n2015-06-30 13:09:13 [INFO] deployer.import: Deploying services...\n2015-06-30 13:09:13 [DEBUG] deployer.import: <deployer.env.go.GoEnvironment object at 0x7f20266b4c50>\n2015-06-30 13:09:13 [INFO] deployer.import:  Deploying service apache2 using cs:trusty/apache2-10\n2015-06-30 13:09:13 [DEBUG] deployer.import:  Refetching status for placement deploys\n2015-06-30 13:09:24 [DEBUG] deployer.import:  Setting annotations\n2015-06-30 13:09:25 [INFO] deployer.import:  Deploying service haproxy using cs:trusty/haproxy-4\n2015-06-30 13:09:32 [DEBUG] deployer.import:  Setting annotations\n2015-06-30 13:09:32 [INFO] deployer.import:  Deploying service landscape using cs:trusty/landscape-server\n2015-06-30 13:09:40 [DEBUG] deployer.import:  Setting annotations\n2015-06-30 13:09:41 [INFO] deployer.import:  Deploying service landscape-msg using cs:trusty/landscape-server\n2015-06-30 13:09:45 [DEBUG] deployer.import:  Setting annotations\n2015-06-30 13:09:46 [INFO] deployer.import:  Deploying service postgresql using cs:trusty/postgresql-15\n2015-06-30 13:09:53 [DEBUG] deployer.import:  Setting annotations\n2015-06-30 13:09:53 [INFO] deployer.import:  Deploying service rabbitmq-server using cs:trusty/rabbitmq-server-26\n2015-06-30 13:09:59 [DEBUG] deployer.import:  Setting annotations\n2015-06-30 13:10:05 [DEBUG] deployer.import: Adding units...\n2015-06-30 13:10:05 [DEBUG] deployer.import:  Service \'apache2\' does not need any more units added.\n2015-06-30 13:10:05 [DEBUG] deployer.import:  Service \'haproxy\' does not need any more units added.\n2015-06-30 13:10:05 [DEBUG] deployer.import:  Service \'landscape\' does not need any more units added.\n2015-06-30 13:10:05 [DEBUG] deployer.import:  Service \'landscape-msg\' does not need any more units added.\n2015-06-30 13:10:05 [DEBUG] deployer.import:  Service \'postgresql\' does not need any more units added.\n2015-06-30 13:10:05 [DEBUG] deployer.import:  Service \'rabbitmq-server\' does not need any more units added.\n2015-06-30 13:10:05 [DEBUG] deployer.import: Waiting for units before adding relations\n2015-06-30 13:11:51 [DEBUG] deployer.env:  Delta machine: 0/lxc/0 change:pending\n2015-06-30 13:12:01 [DEBUG] deployer.env:  Delta machine: 0/lxc/1 change:pending\n2015-06-30 13:12:16 [DEBUG] deployer.env:  Delta machine: 0/lxc/2 change:pending\n2015-06-30 13:12:16 [DEBUG] deployer.env:  Delta machine: 0/lxc/0 change:started\n2015-06-30 13:12:16 [DEBUG] deployer.env:  Delta unit: apache2/0 change:pending\n2015-06-30 13:12:21 [DEBUG] deployer.env:  Delta service: apache2 change:{u\'Err\': None, u\'Since\': u\'2015-06-30T11:12:16Z\', u\'Current\': u\'maintenance\', u\'Version\': u\'\', u\'Message\': u\'installing charm software\', u\'Data\': {}}\n2015-06-30 13:12:21 [DEBUG] deployer.env:  Delta unit: apache2/0 change:pending\n2015-06-30 13:12:26 [DEBUG] deployer.env:  Delta machine: 0/lxc/3 change:pending\n2015-06-30 13:12:26 [DEBUG] deployer.env:  Delta unit: apache2/0 change:pending\n2015-06-30 13:12:46 [DEBUG] deployer.env:  Delta machine: 0/lxc/4 change:pending\n2015-06-30 13:12:51 [DEBUG] deployer.env:  Delta machine: 0/lxc/2 change:pending\n2015-06-30 13:12:51 [DEBUG] deployer.env:  Delta machine: 0/lxc/1 change:started\n2015-06-30 13:12:51 [DEBUG] deployer.env:  Delta machine: 0/lxc/2 change:started\n2015-06-30 13:12:51 [DEBUG] deployer.env:  Delta unit: landscape/0 change:pending\n2015-06-30 13:12:51 [DEBUG] deployer.env:  Delta unit: haproxy/0 change:pending\n2015-06-30 13:12:51 [DEBUG] deployer.env:  Delta service: landscape change:{u\'Err\': None, u\'Since\': u\'2015-06-30T11:12:49Z\', u\'Current\': u\'maintenance\', u\'Version\': u\'\', u\'Message\': u\'installing charm software\', u\'Data\': {}}\n2015-06-30 13:12:51 [DEBUG] deployer.env:  Delta unit: landscape/0 change:pending\n2015-06-30 13:12:51 [DEBUG] deployer.env:  Delta service: haproxy change:{u\'Err\': None, u\'Since\': u\'2015-06-30T11:12:49Z\', u\'Current\': u\'maintenance\', u\'Version\': u\'\', u\'Message\': u\'installing charm software\', u\'Data\': {}}\n2015-06-30 13:12:51 [DEBUG] deployer.env:  Delta unit: haproxy/0 change:pending\n2015-06-30 13:12:51 [DEBUG] deployer.env:  Delta unit: landscape/0 change:pending\n2015-06-30 13:12:51 [DEBUG] deployer.env:  Delta unit: haproxy/0 change:pending\n2015-06-30 13:13:01 [DEBUG] deployer.env:  Delta machine: 0/lxc/5 change:pending\n2015-06-30 13:13:21 [DEBUG] deployer.env:  Delta machine: 0/lxc/3 change:pending\n2015-06-30 13:13:21 [DEBUG] deployer.env:  Delta machine: 0/lxc/4 change:pending\n2015-06-30 13:13:21 [DEBUG] deployer.env:  Delta machine: 0/lxc/3 change:started\n2015-06-30 13:13:21 [DEBUG] deployer.env:  Delta unit: landscape-msg/0 change:pending\n2015-06-30 13:13:26 [DEBUG] deployer.env:  Delta machine: 0/lxc/4 change:started\n2015-06-30 13:13:26 [DEBUG] deployer.env:  Delta unit: landscape-msg/0 change:pending\n2015-06-30 13:13:26 [DEBUG] deployer.env:  Delta unit: postgresql/0 change:pending\n2015-06-30 13:13:26 [DEBUG] deployer.env:  Delta service: landscape-msg change:{u\'Err\': None, u\'Since\': u\'2015-06-30T11:13:24Z\', u\'Current\': u\'maintenance\', u\'Version\': u\'\', u\'Message\': u\'installing charm software\', u\'Data\': {}}\n2015-06-30 13:13:26 [DEBUG] deployer.env:  Delta unit: landscape-msg/0 change:pending\n2015-06-30 13:13:26 [DEBUG] deployer.env:  Delta service: postgresql change:{u\'Err\': None, u\'Since\': u\'2015-06-30T11:13:24Z\', u\'Current\': u\'maintenance\', u\'Version\': u\'\', u\'Message\': u\'installing charm software\', u\'Data\': {}}\n2015-06-30 13:13:26 [DEBUG] deployer.env:  Delta unit: postgresql/0 change:pending\n2015-06-30 13:13:26 [DEBUG] deployer.env:  Delta unit: landscape-msg/0 change:pending\n2015-06-30 13:13:26 [DEBUG] deployer.env:  Delta unit: postgresql/0 change:pending\n2015-06-30 13:13:36 [DEBUG] deployer.env:  Delta machine: 0/lxc/5 change:pending\n2015-06-30 13:13:36 [DEBUG] deployer.env:  Delta unit: haproxy/0 change:pending\n2015-06-30 13:13:36 [DEBUG] deployer.env:  Delta machine: 0/lxc/5 change:started\n2015-06-30 13:13:36 [DEBUG] deployer.env:  Delta unit: rabbitmq-server/0 change:pending\n2015-06-30 13:13:41 [DEBUG] deployer.env:  Delta unit: rabbitmq-server/0 change:pending\n2015-06-30 13:13:46 [DEBUG] deployer.env:  Delta service: rabbitmq-server change:{u\'Err\': None, u\'Since\': u\'2015-06-30T11:13:41Z\', u\'Current\': u\'maintenance\', u\'Version\': u\'\', u\'Message\': u\'installing charm software\', u\'Data\': {}}\n2015-06-30 13:13:46 [DEBUG] deployer.env:  Delta unit: rabbitmq-server/0 change:pending\n2015-06-30 13:13:46 [DEBUG] deployer.env:  Delta unit: rabbitmq-server/0 change:pending\n2015-06-30 13:13:51 [DEBUG] deployer.env:  Delta service: haproxy change:{u\'Err\': None, u\'Since\': u\'2015-06-30T11:13:49Z\', u\'Current\': u\'unknown\', u\'Version\': u\'\', u\'Message\': u\'\', u\'Data\': {}}\n2015-06-30 13:13:51 [DEBUG] deployer.env:  Delta unit: haproxy/0 change:pending\n2015-06-30 13:13:51 [DEBUG] deployer.env:  Delta unit: haproxy/0 change:started\n2015-06-30 13:13:56 [DEBUG] deployer.env:  Delta unit: haproxy/0 change:started\n2015-06-30 13:14:06 [DEBUG] deployer.env:  Delta unit: apache2/0 change:pending\n2015-06-30 13:14:11 [DEBUG] deployer.env:  Delta unit: apache2/0 change:pending\n2015-06-30 13:14:21 [DEBUG] deployer.env:  Delta service: apache2 change:{u\'Err\': None, u\'Since\': u\'2015-06-30T11:14:20Z\', u\'Current\': u\'unknown\', u\'Version\': u\'\', u\'Message\': u\'\', u\'Data\': {}}\n2015-06-30 13:14:21 [DEBUG] deployer.env:  Delta unit: apache2/0 change:pending\n2015-06-30 13:14:21 [DEBUG] deployer.env:  Delta unit: apache2/0 change:started\n2015-06-30 13:14:26 [DEBUG] deployer.env:  Delta unit: apache2/0 change:started\n2015-06-30 13:14:46 [DEBUG] deployer.env:  Delta unit: postgresql/0 change:pending\n2015-06-30 13:14:46 [DEBUG] deployer.env:  Delta unit: postgresql/0 change:pending\n2015-06-30 13:14:51 [DEBUG] deployer.env:  Delta unit: postgresql/0 change:pending\n2015-06-30 13:14:56 [DEBUG] deployer.env:  Delta service: postgresql change:{u\'Err\': None, u\'Since\': u\'2015-06-30T11:14:51Z\', u\'Current\': u\'unknown\', u\'Version\': u\'\', u\'Message\': u\'\', u\'Data\': {}}\n2015-06-30 13:14:56 [DEBUG] deployer.env:  Delta unit: postgresql/0 change:started\n2015-06-30 13:14:56 [DEBUG] deployer.env:  Delta unit: postgresql/0 change:started\n2015-06-30 13:15:21 [DEBUG] deployer.env:  Delta unit: rabbitmq-server/0 change:pending\n2015-06-30 13:16:46 [DEBUG] deployer.env:  Delta unit: rabbitmq-server/0 change:pending\n2015-06-30 13:16:46 [DEBUG] deployer.env:  Delta service: rabbitmq-server change:{u\'Err\': None, u\'Since\': u\'2015-06-30T11:16:45Z\', u\'Current\': u\'unknown\', u\'Version\': u\'\', u\'Message\': u\'\', u\'Data\': {}}\n2015-06-30 13:16:46 [DEBUG] deployer.env:  Delta unit: rabbitmq-server/0 change:pending\n2015-06-30 13:16:46 [DEBUG] deployer.env:  Delta unit: rabbitmq-server/0 change:started\n2015-06-30 13:16:51 [DEBUG] deployer.env:  Delta unit: rabbitmq-server/0 change:started\n2015-06-30 13:20:26 [DEBUG] deployer.env:  Delta unit: landscape-msg/0 change:pending\n2015-06-30 13:20:31 [DEBUG] deployer.env:  Delta service: landscape-msg change:{u\'Err\': None, u\'Since\': u\'2015-06-30T11:20:29Z\', u\'Current\': u\'unknown\', u\'Version\': u\'\', u\'Message\': u\'\', u\'Data\': {}}\n2015-06-30 13:20:31 [DEBUG] deployer.env:  Delta unit: landscape-msg/0 change:pending\n2015-06-30 13:20:31 [DEBUG] deployer.env:  Delta unit: landscape-msg/0 change:started\n2015-06-30 13:20:31 [DEBUG] deployer.env:  Delta unit: landscape/0 change:pending\n2015-06-30 13:20:36 [DEBUG] deployer.env:  Delta unit: landscape-msg/0 change:started\n2015-06-30 13:20:36 [DEBUG] deployer.env:  Delta service: landscape change:{u\'Err\': None, u\'Since\': u\'2015-06-30T11:20:34Z\', u\'Current\': u\'unknown\', u\'Version\': u\'\', u\'Message\': u\'\', u\'Data\': {}}\n2015-06-30 13:20:36 [DEBUG] deployer.env:  Delta unit: landscape/0 change:started\n2015-06-30 13:20:36 [DEBUG] deployer.env: Connecting to environment...\n2015-06-30 13:20:37 [DEBUG] deployer.env: Connected to environment\n2015-06-30 13:20:37 [INFO] deployer.import: Adding relations...\n2015-06-30 13:20:37 [INFO] deployer.import:  Adding relation landscape <-> rabbitmq-server\n2015-06-30 13:20:37 [INFO] deployer.import:  Adding relation landscape <-> haproxy\n2015-06-30 13:20:38 [INFO] deployer.import:  Adding relation landscape:vhost-config <-> apache2:vhost-config\n2015-06-30 13:20:38 [INFO] deployer.import:  Adding relation landscape:db-admin <-> postgresql:db-admin\n2015-06-30 13:20:38 [INFO] deployer.import:  Adding relation haproxy:website <-> apache2:reverseproxy\n2015-06-30 13:20:39 [INFO] deployer.import:  Adding relation landscape-msg <-> rabbitmq-server\n2015-06-30 13:20:39 [INFO] deployer.import:  Adding relation landscape-msg <-> haproxy\n2015-06-30 13:20:40 [INFO] deployer.import:  Adding relation landscape-msg:db-admin <-> postgresql:db-admin\n2015-06-30 13:20:40 [DEBUG] deployer.import: Waiting for relation convergence 180s\n2015-06-30 13:23:40 [ERROR] deployer.env: The following units had errors:\n   unit: postgresql/0: machine: 0/lxc/4 agent-state: error details: hook failed: "db-admin-relation-changed"\n2015-06-30 13:23:40 [INFO] deployer.cli: Deployment stopped. run time: 869.59\n'}
[DEBUG • 06-30 13:23:40] • cloudinstall.utils • (utils.py, global_exchandler, 63)]
   Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/usr/share/openstack/cloudinstall/utils.py", line 78, in run
    super().run()
  File "/usr/lib/python3.4/threading.py", line 868, in run
    self._target(*self._args, **self._kwargs)
  File "/usr/share/openstack/cloudinstall/machinewait.py", line 127, in do_continue
    self.installer.do_install()
  File "/usr/share/openstack/cloudinstall/multi_install.py", line 177, in do_install
    self.loop).run()
  File "/usr/share/openstack/cloudinstall/multi_install.py", line 708, in run
    self.deploy_landscape()
  File "/usr/share/openstack/cloudinstall/multi_install.py", line 731, in deploy_landscape
    self.run_deployer()
  File "/usr/share/openstack/cloudinstall/multi_install.py", line 771, in run_deployer
    raise Exception("Error deploying Landscape.")
Exception: Error deploying Landscape.

[INFO  • 06-30 13:24:50] • cloudinstall.utils • (utils.py, cleanup, 91)]
   Cleanup, saving latest config object.
[DEBUG • 06-30 13:24:50] • cloudinstall.utils • (utils.py, cleanup, 97)]
   Attempting to reset the terminal
```

(Full log is at http://pastebin.com/raw.php?i=Nr1qy50j.)

I note that MAAS marks one node as 'Deployed' quite a time before this error occurs and that that node is powered on; the others remain 'Ready' and are powered off.

Help!: I've done plenty of googling, found plenty of references to juju and stuff I was hoping not to have to become familiar with so soon, but not come across a good match for this particular error. Any ideas please? Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

Make sure you've set the power management in the MAAS UI so MAAS knows how to power on/off the VM's. See here for more information: [How to configure MAAS to be able to boot virtual machines](https://askubuntu.com/questions/292061/how-to-configure-maas-to-be-able-to-boot-virtual-machines)

The other problem I see is that you seem to be running the installer as root. As per our documentation you'll want to run the installer as a normal non-root user. More information on running the installer can be found here: http://ubuntu-cloud-installer.readthedocs.org/en/latest/multi-installer.guide.html

If you've already done both of these please pastebin the full commands.log.

Comment: MAAS can toggle power on the VMs without problem (if I tell it to power on, it does so). I'm redoing the installation as non-root now. Could you clarify whether my doc link is made obsolete by your doc link? Will pastebin commands.log in an hour or so.

Comment: That doc is not obsolete, the one I provided just contains additional details

Comment: Reran it as non-root. Same error. Link to pastebin'd full commands.log added above.